# custom messages under rosjava indigo

Tags: matlab, rosjava, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ros indigo on Xubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS)

I want to create some custom messages for consumption in both Matlab and C++
I'm working on the assumption that in order to do this I need rosjava to generate a jar file from my custom message package.

I've followed the Indigo tutorial for installing rosjava from source. I then started working through the Hydro tutorials only to find that these seem no longer applicable. In the end I simply copied the custom messages package from my catkin_ws/src into my rosjava/src and tried a catkin_make. This seems to have worked but given the complexity of this process under Hydro and can't help feeling I might be missing something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200610/custom-messages-under-rosjava-indigo/) by [shaun@createc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21321/shaun@createc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After further testing we have satisfied ourselves that the process under Indigo is now just a simple catkin_make.

---

Originally posted by [shaun@createc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21321/shaun@createc/) with karma: 16 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0